# Change language contact form

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, contacts

I have made 2 contact forms in WP, contactform and contactform_fr.

If the language is changed to French, i would like to show contactform_fr.

I found this is the footer.php

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                <h2><?php the_field("title", 34); ?></h2>
                <?php echo do_shortcode("[contact-form-7 id='89' title='Contact']"); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar("footer-widget-1"); ?>
            </div>
```

Can i change it here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change it there, in case you use WPML plugin to translate your website:

```
<?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'); ?>
      <?php echo do_shortcode("[contact-form-7 id='89' title='Contact']"); ?>
<?php elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='fr'); ?>
      <?php echo do_shortcode("[contact-form-7 id='something' title='Something']"); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can read more about it in WPML coding APi https://wpml.org/documentation/support/wpml-coding-api/

In case you use qtranslate plugin you can use:

```
<? if(get_language_code()=='EN'): ?>
     <?php echo do_shortcode("[contact-form-7 id='89' title='Contact']"); ?>
<? elseif(get_language_code()=='FR'): ?>
     <?php echo do_shortcode("[contact-form-7 id='something' title='Something']"); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Make sure you're editing in your child theme file, an update can override these changes.